# How to change default LC_TYPE?

Tags: terminal, ssh, command-line, iterm

My OS X (Mavericks) seems to be setting `LC_CTYPE` environmental variable to `UTF-8` by default.

How can I change the default? I need `LC_CTYPE` to be `en_US.UTF-8`.

**There's a catch**: I don't want to *overwrite* default with another value by using `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` in my local `.profile` or `.bash_rc`. I'm interested in *changing* the default itself, at the very root wherever it comes from, so that it works *without* additional startup scripts (and also I'm curious what controls env vars in OS X :)

The reason I want to change it at the very source is that I want to be able to:

- launch remote shell quickly in iTerm2, which doesn't run local shell's (slow-ish) startup script
- have remote servers inherit my local `LC_` variables so that I have UTF-8 support on other machines without having to configure them specifically.

Comment: adding `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` doesn't overwrite anything. You always log into your shell via your $PATH. Otherwise you'd be presented with `bash [version] #` as in recovery mode Terminal. Explicitly including this in your profile is equivalent to modifying the setting described in the answer below. The benefit of including it in your path is that is explicitly defines the ENV for $HOME. This is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal.app you can change the default encoding in the Advanced settings. This will be set before it spawns a shell.

Looks like iTerm2 has the setting under Preferences, Profiles, Terminal.

Is that 'the very source' you are looking for?